# "Weak" bijection between $\mathbb{Z^n}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ where tuple-order is dropped?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Background:**

I am looking for an explicit (construction, formula, or description of a) family of functions over $n$, $f:\mathbb{Z}^n\to\mathbb{Z}$ such that, given $f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$, without prior knowledge of $x_1,\cdots,x_n$, one could deduce the multiset {$x_1,\cdots,x_n$}, but not their order (as arguments of $f$)?

That is to say, for example, in the case of $n=2$, $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$.

Notice that this is slightly weaker than a bijection between $\mathbb{Z}^n$ and $\mathbb{Z}$.

---

**My Work:**

I have figured out a dirty way to do this for the case of $n=2$ by first considering a function $g:\mathbb{Z^2}\to\mathbb{Z^2}$ by taking $$g(x,y)=(x+y,|x-y|).$$

This essentially "strips" the argument-order. Notice, for instance, if we know that $g(x,y)=(g_1,g_2)$ then we can reconstruct the multiset {$x,y$} by taking {$x,y$}={$\alpha, \beta$} where $\alpha=\frac{g_1-g_2}{2}$, $\beta=\frac{g_1+g_2}{2}$, as $g(\alpha, \beta)=g(\beta, \alpha)=(g_1,g_2)$.

To complete this construction, we may take our favorite *actual* bijection $\phi:\mathbb{Z}^2\to\mathbb{Z}$ and declare
$f(x,y)=\phi(g_1,g_2)$.

---

From here what is the most natural extension to any $\mathbb{Z}^n$? Also, I would appreciate any "nicer" alternative to my $g$ or $f$. The domain is not super important. While editing I swapped between using $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$, so whatever finds a good balance between the simplicity of a smaller domain, and the the convenience of generalizing to larger domains, I would be content with.

**Note:** I suppose I am asking for a bijection between the family of multisets {$X\subseteq \mathbb{Z}:0<|X|\leq n$} and $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: As a tangent, I seem to have difficulty rendering the MathJax while editing and rendering this question. This may be due to my internet, but I'm curious if any others have noticed that too.

Comment: As your very last sentences makes clear, such a function definitely exists, as both sets are countably infinite. You should probably edit your question from "exists" to "seeking explicit formula".

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC very true, will do so.

Comment: Hmm, thinking about this more, can you clarify whether you mean "set" or "multiset" when you say "...  one could deduce the set $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$". E.g. should $f(1,1,1,2,2)$ be the same as $f(1,1,2,2,2)$? I've realized that  my answer would have them be different, but a strict interpretation of the word "set", i.e. no duplicates, would lead to $f$ giving them the same value.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC ahh, I'm glad you caught that. I failed to think about such a case. $f(1,1,1,2,2)$ should be **distinct** from $f(1,1,2,2,2)$. So what I actually mean is multiset, which I think is what your answer also assumes?

Comment: Yep, my answer assumed "multiset", so it still applies. You could update your question to indicate that - I think there's only two places that need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to "strip the argument order" your first step could be "sort them (into ascending order)".

I don't think there's any particularly nice formula for that map, but it's perfectly well defined. I know in my comment I suggested you ask for an "explicit formula", whereas you only asked for an "explicit ... function". I'd say this suggestion fails to meet my standard; you'll have to decide if it meets yours.

Anyways, you would again follow that with your favorite $\phi:\mathbb{Z}^n\to\mathbb{Z}$ to complete your construction.

---

BTW, I don't know if you're into category theory, and characterizing universal objects by the existence of maps that factor through another map, but if you are.... I think the "sort 'em" map might be universal for any map that does what you want. I.e. any such map should be writeable as sorting followed by some other map. So in some sense the construction above describes all such maps. Though it does so without any consideration of how nice or elegant the maps are, which I believe is part of your question.

Comment: That is a nice way of doing so. I suppose what this approach generally surmounts to is first imposing an order on the arguments, independent of the order they appear in the argument-tuple, and then using a bijection.

Comment: In this context, what distinction do you make between asking for an explicit function vs formula? I must admit that I consider the terms interchangeable in this context.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure there is one. If I'd asked for a formula and someone answered "sort 'em", I'd reply "please show me the formula for the third term in five dimensions", because I think it would be a horrible thing of min's over multiple subsets. But "sort 'em" is a fine _description_ for a function.

Comment: Thanks for the category theory addition. It is certainly something I'm interested in, so I will certainly keep that in my toolkit. I think this dialog has certainly answered my big questions and cleared up a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The function $\sigma:\mathbb{Z}^n\to\mathbb{Z}^n$ that takes $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ to $(\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_n)$ where
$$
   \prod_{i=1}^n (T+x_i) = T^n + \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i T^{n-i}
$$ is a function that "goes modulo" the order of the numbers $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. The functions $\sigma_i$ are polynomials in the variables $x_i$ and are called "elementary symmetric polynomials".

Let us say that a function $g:\mathbb{Z}^n\to\mathbb{Z}$ such that $g(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ does not depend on the order of $x_i$'s is an "invariant function".

Given any function $f:\mathbb{Z}^n\to\mathbb{Z}$ we get an invariant function $f\circ\sigma$. Thus, if $f$ is any one-to-one function from $\mathbb{Z}^n\to\mathbb{Z}$, then $f\circ\sigma$ would satisfy your requirement that the value of $f$ determines the multiset.

*Caution*: Note that $\sigma$ is *not* surjective. For example, if $n=2$, then a point $(a,b)$ in the image of $\sigma$ satisfies $a^2-4b$ is the square of an integer. Thus, it would not be correct to say that *every* invariant function is a function of the form $f\circ\sigma$.

Comment: Yes, thank you for adding this. Maybe add the name "elementary symmetric polynomials" to your answer, for further reference? I think this makes a great contrast to my answer, as the $\sigma_i$ have much nicer explicit formulas, but it's much harder to find the $\{x_i\}$ for a given set of $\{\sigma_i\}$.